# Using TempDB in SP causes to compile plan PER CONNECTION

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, tempdb

uses sp_blitzcache by Brent Ozar

SQL SERVER 2012 (11.0.6020.0)

Steps to reproduce:

```
create table b (b int)
create table #b (b int)

create procedure Y as
begin
insert into b select 1
select * from b
insert into #b select 1
select * from #b
end
```

open two query windows in MS SSMS.
run

```
checkpoint
go
dbcc freeproccache
go
```

in both of them (just to be sure)
run **sp_blitzcache**
this will return empty (ok)

run procedure **Y** in both few times.
run **sp_blitzcache**
As can be seen, the procedure has a plan compiled for each connection separately

My question is:

Is there any way around? For the same stored procedure to use the same plan, even trogh the (right now this causes over 80% recompile)

Comment: It is likely getting recomped because of the temp table. you can verify by running a profiler trace / extended event session and capture recomplies, it will give you the reason.

Comment: @RyanCooper Yes, it IS recomped because of the temp table. That i know now of FACT. What i am looking for right now are accepted solutions, how-tos and patterns to solve this...

Comment: I would test using OPTION (RECOMPILE) on your queries that reference the temp table. It is possible this could force only a statement-level recomp rather than the entire procedure.

Comment: Using OPTION(KEEP PLAN) may help here, since the recompile is specifically for the temp table.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Thanks for that, but doesnt seem to work out :(

Comment: Okay, what I would do is run profiler or XE and capture the reason for the recompile.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Will try Profiler. XE?

Comment: To be more precise, the example is that  - EXAMPLE. The reallife application does the same on a bigger scale, about 50 temp tables are created per connection, filled with Customers, Orders, atc mid-results that are used in later queries (ie. Orders are selected based on Customers stored in tmp table)....
One more question: How much of an impact could this have on speed of DB server? Is it worthwile to follow this lead or is it just an interesting thing to know?